# Want to animate 2 scatter and one plot, but not happening

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am adding small values to x and y, but as don't know much about so Please help me with this.
Basic concern I have is how I can move 2 scatter on the corner of the 1 plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xori = 0.007
xdest = 0.5
yori = 0.97
ydest = 0.5

line, = ax.plot([0.007, 0.97], [0.5, 0.5], c='C2', zorder=1, alpha=0.2, linewidth=1)
dotOne = ax.scatter(0.007, 0.5, s=80, c='C2', zorder=2)
dotTwo = ax.scatter(0.97, 0.5,  s=80, c='C2', zorder=2)


def animate(xori, xdest, yori, ydest):
    print("called")
    xori = xori + 0.001
    xdest = xdest - 0.01
    yori = yori + 0.001
    ydest = ydest - 0.01
    line.set_xdata([xori, xdest])
    line.set_ydata([yori, ydest])
    dotOne.set_offsets([xori,yori])
    dotTwo.set_offsets([xdest,ydest])    
    return line, dotOne, dotTwo

#anim = animate(xori, xdest, yori, ydest)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate(xori, xdest, yori, ydest), interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `function`, not the result of the function. You may use global variable to change the values inside the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xori = 0.007
xdest = 0.5
yori = 0.97
ydest = 0.5

line, = ax.plot([0.007, 0.97], [0.5, 0.5], c='C2', zorder=1, alpha=0.2, linewidth=1)
dotOne = ax.scatter(0.007, 0.5, s=80, c='C2', zorder=2)
dotTwo = ax.scatter(0.97, 0.5,  s=80, c='C2', zorder=2)
ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-3,3))

def animate(i):
    global xori, xdest, yori, ydest
    xori = xori + 0.001
    xdest = xdest - 0.01
    yori = yori + 0.001
    ydest = ydest - 0.01
    line.set_xdata([xori, xdest])
    line.set_ydata([yori, ydest])
    dotOne.set_offsets([xori,yori])
    dotTwo.set_offsets([xdest,ydest])    
    return line, dotOne, dotTwo

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize that I have just started to learn this and without knowing basic I have started.